# C# connection becomes null

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, null, connection

I'm developing a class to manage the operations on a Mysql database.
I have the following code:

```
 using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public class MysqlAccess
{
    private MySqlConnection pCnn;
    public enum OperationType {Select = 1,Insert = 2,Update = 3,Delete = 4};

    public MysqlAccess()
    {

        MySqlConnection Connection=new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalMySqlServer"].ConnectionString);


    }

   public MySqlConnection Connection { get {return pCnn;} set {pCnn=value;} }


    public int Connect()
    {
        try
        {

            Connection.Open();

            if (Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return -1;

        }
    }



    }

}
```

Page Load Code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MysqlAccess DBManager = new MysqlAccess();


        DBManager.Connect();
        Response.Write("Connection State:" + DBManager.Connection.State.ToString());
    }
```

When i do the response.write the connection is null, why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you all for your help.
It seems i was making some confusion with the Connection word =)

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it is null because you never really initialize the `Connection` property and it will be null until you initialize it. So instead of:

```
public MysqlAccess()
{
    // Here you are initializing a local variable 
    // that is subject to GC and goes into the void of forgetfulness
    MySqlConnection Connection=new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalMySqlServer"].ConnectionString);
}
```

initialize the property:

```
public MysqlAccess()
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalMySqlServer"].ConnectionString;
    // The 'this' keyword is optional here and its usage is a 
    // matter of personal preference
    this.Connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
}
```

While this might fix the [NullReferenceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx) you are getting you should be aware that `MySqlConnection` implements [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) meaning that you should make sure to call the [Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) method to avoid leaking connections or creating new connections on each request which could be particularly catastrophic in a web application.

Answer (score 2):

In the constructor, you are not setting the property Connection. You're are declaring a local variable Connection. So, you've never initializes the property Connection.

Correct the code, using:

```
this.Connection=new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalMySqlServer"].ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you declared Connection as a local variable here:

```
public MysqlAccess()
{

    MySqlConnection Connection=new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalMySqlServer"].ConnectionString);


}
```

Try

```
public MysqlAccess()
{

    Connection=new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalMySqlServer"].ConnectionString);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your constructor to:

```
public MysqlAccess()
{
    Connection=new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalMySqlServer"].ConnectionString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `MysqlAccess` constructor you assign to a new local variable:

```
MySqlConnection Connection=new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalMySqlServer"].ConnectionString);
```

...then later on you refer to a property, which happens to have the same name as the local variable:

```
Response.Write("Connection State:" + DBManager.Connection.State.ToString());
```

Changing the `MySqlConnection Connection` to just `Connection` in the constructor should fix it.